# How can I keep one part of an application responsive when other parts are not so?

Tags: language-agnostic, rdp

I use RDP sessions a lot, and I noticed that, even if the server I connect to is slow or crashed, the RDP window/toolbar itself is fully responsive/clickable. This is probably due to the RDP window is one process and the actual server is seperate - or not?

Is there a technique in development to achieve this sort of fluidity in an app?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used RDP much, but i assume the toolbar is being handled by the client, not the server.  That'd be why it's responsive even when the server isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single most important thing you can do to keep the UI responsive is to minimize the amount of work you do in the UI thread.  This means that any major processing you have to do, you spawn a thread (or use the thread pool) to offload the work so that the UI thread can get back to handling the UI.

Comment: The event thread (which handles UI actions and redraws) should never block for more than about 1/10 a second.

Comment: That's what i learned too.  But frankly, i learned it like 15 years ago.  Even 1/10 of a second can be a mind-numbingly long time these days, considering the processing power available (and the expectations that go along with it).  The sooner you can get back to handling the next event, the more responsive the app will appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

It probably aren't two separate processes, but two separate threads. A thread is somewhat like a sub-process.

There are applications that use more that one process, like Windows Explorer and Google Chrome. Each window or tab has as separate process. There is one process displaying it, but separate processes managing their content. This is mainly done because of possible instabilities. When a process crashes, the entire application is closed, including all its threads. By putting the logic in separate processes, the application stays alive when one of the windows crashes. It's a little harder to program a multi-threaded application, but a lot little harder to develop a multi-process single window application like this.